# Issues with Counting Records with SQL across multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are three tables: Cases, Calls, and SubEvents.

The table schema is a Case can have multiple Calls, and each Call can have multiple SubEvents.
I'd like to use a query to get a count of all calls and a count of all sub-events (if there are any) for each case after a certain date.

For example, a case named John has 3 calls... the first call has 2 sub-events, the second call has 1 sub-event, and the third call has zero. So the query should return this result:

| Case | Call Total | SubEvent Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 3 | 3 |

I've tried writing the query multiple ways, with subqueries etc, but I can't get it to work properly. The closest I've come is the query below, but this provides the incorrect count for Calls. It gives me 4 when it should give me 3. Another example I tried had 4 calls with 10 sub-events, but the query returned 11 total calls instead of 4.

I'd appreciate any help. My SQL has gotten rusty after a period of disuse, and this is in someone's Access database, which is pretty fickle when it comes to writing SQL queries.

```
SELECT c.casename, Count(e.callid) AS EventTotal, Count(s.id) AS SubEventTotal
FROM (cases AS c INNER JOIN calls AS e ON c.contactid = e.contactid) left JOIN tblSubEvents AS s ON e.callid = s.callid
WHERE e.calldate > #1/1/2022#
GROUP BY c.casename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   c.casename
   ,Count(e.callid) AS EventTotal
   ,sum(s.id) AS SubEventTotal
FROM (cases AS c INNER JOIN calls AS e ON c.contactid = e.contactid)
left JOIN (select callid, count(s.id) as id from tblSubEvents s group by callid) AS s ON e.callid = s.callid
WHERE e.calldate > #1/1/2022#
GROUP BY c.casename
```

Basically, pushing the responsibility for the sub-event count to the join query.

Comment: Query will not compile in Access. Hint: check second `ON` clause and Access' parentheses requirement for multiple `JOIN`s.

Comment: Thank you, Chris! This worked perfectly and gave me the accurate numbers. I'll be able to expand on it from here. Thanks again, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining two aggregate derived tables:

```sql
SELECT case.casename, c_agg.EventTotal, e_agg.SubEventTotal
FROM (case
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT contactid, COUNT(callid) AS EventTotal
    FROM calls
    WHERE calldate > CDate('2022-01-01')
    GROUP BY contactid
) c_agg
  ON case.contactid = c_agg.contactid)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT callid, COUNT(id) AS SubEventTotal
    FROM tblSubEvents
    GROUP BY callid
) e_agg
  ON c_agg.callid = e_agg.callid
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The previous answer worked for me, but I will keep this in mind for next time. Thanks!